# Duplicate commits in history after fork

Tags: git, github

I originally forked a repository from github and made many changes to it. In the meantime, the original repository changed and I wanted to merge the changes into my current fork.

I added the original repo as an upstream branch, and performed fetch. When I look at the git log, it seems that all the commits up to my fork (which I expected to be the mutual ancestor) are duplicated (same name but different commit ids).

What could cause this?
How can I merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause is : on the original repo, someone ran a history rewriting command (for example `git rebase -i ...` or `git filter-branch ...`), which created commits with identical messages but distinct commit ids.

IMHO, the easiest way to fix this would be : rebase your own commits on top of the new commits.

With this suggestion however, you would rewrite the history of your branch, so you would need to `push --force` your branch to your fork afterwards.
I will guess that this is ok in your case, but if this is a blocker please add a comment.

---

Here is a diagram to name commits :

```
*--*--*--*--A--B--C--X <- fork/master   # the original commit from upstream,
          \           \                 # on which you started your branch
           \           *--*--*--*--Y <- yourbranch
            \
             A'--B'--C'--X'--*--*--Z <- upstream/master
```

By inspecting the history of your commits and `upstream`'s commit, you should find out rather easily which commit are `X` and `X'` in the diagram above.

When you have spotted this commit, you can either :

1. rebase your branch directly on top of `Z`
2. first rebase your branch on top of `X'`, then on top of `Z`

With the 2nd way : the first rebase should have much less conflicts, and you would have this intermediate state, where `yourbranch` is correctly integrated in the new history of `upstream`.

---

To rebase a sequence of commits on top of another point : use `git rebase --onto` :

```
# to rebase X..yourbranch on top of X' :
git rebase --onto X' X yourbranch

# to rebase X'..yourbranch on top of Z :
git rebase --onto Z X' yourbranch

# obviously, if you want to go with 1. :
git rebase --onto Z X yourbranch
```

Comment: The OP stated that all commits up to the fork are duplicates, in other words - there is no common ancestor. Would this answer work in such case as well?

Comment: Also, it could make sense (depending on the git methodology used) to do rebase onto X', then merge from Z.

Comment: @Michael Litvin : yes, this answer would also work if there is no common ancestor. When you use the `--onto` option of `git rebase`, `git` does not need to compute a merge base anymore.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I'm not sure why, though. In my case, unlike in your diagram, the two repositories didn't have a common ancestor (like @MichaelLitvin pointed out). How can git technically perform a rebase without a merge base in this case? Doesn't it need a common base in order to correctly apply diffs?

Comment: @OphirS : it is technically possible to tell `git rebase` to rewrite all commits including the first one (`--root` option), but it is more likely the result of a `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` operation -- these tools are recommended, for example, if you want to delete some specific files from the history of your repository.

Comment: What I meant was that I don't understand how git knew to properly perform the rebase that I just did based on your advice (not the original history replacement). I would expect it to require a common ancestor at some point in history. Otherwise if no connection is needed whatsoever, this should theoretically work for any two unrelated repositories. Which I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: oh : `git rebase` is `git cherry-pick` in a loop ; `git cherry-pick` consists in applying a patch ("the patch introduced to that commit over there on top of here"), so there technically doesn't need to be a common ancestor.

Comment: I thought a regular `git rebase` needed a common ancestor to work, but I re-tested, and it turns out it accepts to rebase an unrelated branch on top of another.